# Upgrading to latest Createjs version from May 2013 version

Tags: createjs

This was the standard boiler plate I was using:

```
var stage = new createjs.Stage("canvas1");
createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick",stage);
stage.enableMouseOver();
...
createjs.Ticker.setFPS(12);
createjs.Ticker.addListener(stage,false);
```

Apparently createjs.Ticker.addListener is no longer supported. How should the above code be changed?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. The first usage is correct `createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick",stage);`.

Comment: createjs.Ticker.addListener(stage,false); -- is no longer supported

Comment: examples: https://gist.github.com/im007boy/3959027 and http://jsfiddle.net/lannymcnie/Aprdf/

Answer (score 4):

Your example shows both the correct and deprecated usage.

```
// OLD
createjs.Ticker.addListener(stage,false);

// NEW
createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", stage);
//OR
createjs.Ticker.on("tick", stage);
```

The changes make Ticker use the same Event dispatcher pattern that the rest of CreateJS does.

Additionally, the framerate method has changed to a setter:

```
// OLD
createjs.Ticker.setFPS(12);

// NEW
createjs.Ticker.framerate = 12;
```

It will depend on what version you use of EaselJS. I updated the demo you posted to the latest version using those changes: http://jsfiddle.net/lannymcnie/Aprdf/80/

Unfortunately there are still demos out there with out-of-date code. Let me know if you have any other questions.